# Почему-то ускоряется процесс игры

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Создал 2д игру (космический корабль сбивает корабли пришельцев, вид сверху)
на `Python 3` с помощью `pygame`. Все работает, но когда я сбиваю все корабли пришельцев, и на экране ничего не остается, кроме основного корабля, то скорость корабля/скорость пуль увеличивается раза в 2-3, хотя в своей программе я такое не прописывал, да и вообще, с каждым сбитым кораблем прищельца, скорость всего, чего только можно, увеличивается. Ноутбук у меня ни разу не слабый, так что я не верю, что он не в состоянии тянуть 2д игру) Это такая особенность `pygame`? Если да, то как это исправить?

Comment: Нет, это не особенность pygame. Исправлять нужно код, который вы не показали

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо) код слишком большой,чтобы его показывать)

Comment: Удаляйте из кода по максимуму всё лишнее (пришельцев, управление, рандом, картинки и т.п.) до тех пор, пока проблема будет оставаться — в итоге должен получиться [mcve], который можно будет вставить в текст вопроса

Comment: В коде косяк и это 100500%. Не спорьте. Ищите и исправляйте :)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я не спорю)

Comment: Похоже на игнорирование времени отрисовки предыдущего кадра, без кода невозможно привести причину. Голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, т.к. непонятна суть вопроса. "код слишком большой" - не аргумент.

Comment: я думаю, это хорошо. Можно добавить что-то типа постепенного усложнения. Я не шучу, в Space Invaders такая же штука была, в начале лагало, а затем ускорялось, и это круто

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с тем же самым. Игра где корабль сбивает пришельцев. Даже не знаю почему, когда сделал передвижение пришельцев и стрельбу, с каждым сбитым пришельцем скорость игры увеличивалась, всех сущностей, всего чего только можно. Мне помог один способ - ограничить частоту кадров. Я тоже ничего не делал такого в коде, чтобы игра ускорялась. Вот, что помогло:

```
pygame.init()

FPS = xx # нужное значение фпс.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


While True: #Основной цикл игры
# Ваши функции
clock.tick(FPS)
```

Очень странно, но при 60 кадров все было медленным, я поставил 200 и все наладилось.